# Compiling C code in the terminal

Tags: compiling, c

I've been having a problem with compiling.

I used the following test C code below and saved it as test.c in Home folder.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Bruh!");
  return 0;
}
```

When I run in terminal the code

```
 gcc test.c -o test
```

I get  nothing. 
Thank you

Comment: Did you run `./test`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are compiling the code, not running it, the correct procedure is:

- Create the source file (`test.c`)
- Compile it with `gcc test.c -o test`
- Run it with `./test`

Also you can make a oneliner with these commands:

```
gcc test.c -o test; ./test
```